# Why is GET variable ignored by gettext?

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, gettext

```
<?php
putenv('LC_ALL=de_DE');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');

$setLng= htmlspecialchars($_GET["lang"]);
//putenv('LC_ALL=$setLng');
//setlocale(LC_ALL, '$setLng');

// translation path
bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");

// Choosing domain
textdomain("messages");

// translation searched in ./locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/meinePHPApp.mo 

?>

<hi><?php echo _("Translate using gettext") ?></h1>
<p> <?php echo _("This video is a simple tutorial.") ?></p>

<?php echo "Set Languange:" .$setLng  //shows current setting  and hows me that variable is correctly fetched...
?>
```

so i am fetching the variable "lang" via GET ($setLng). The output is correct, however it just doesnt work. When I enter the variable within the code (without fetching), it works without problems.

```
putenv('LC_ALL=$setLng');
setlocale(LC_ALL, '$setLng');
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [double-quote (and not single-quote)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in your string:

```
putenv("LC_ALL=$setLng");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "$setLng");
```

By using single-quote php don't reconginse the variables inside your string, and the output will be the string with the `$` sign (and not the value inside your variable).

This is from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it.

Check this:

```
echo 'LC_ALL=$setLng';
echo "<br />\n";
echo "LC_ALL=$setLng";
```

The output will be"

```
LC_ALL=$setLng
LC_ALL=de_DE
```

(based on the fact the your URL is `http://.../?lang=de_DE`).

Comment: the weird thing was it DID show me the value! However, changing the quotes did the trick... Thanks!

Comment: Not so sure where exactly it show you the value... but using the single-quote it probably didn't.